# Spring DB support best practices

Tags: hibernate, spring, jdbc

I'm refreshing my Spring knowledge, reading the reference documentation for spring 3.1. Last time i read about spring as best practice was set `JdbcDaoSupport` and `HibernateDaoSupport`, now they are not even mentioned.
Also I have the impression that `HibernateTemplete` is not preferable any more, instead we just inject the `SessionFactory` in the DAO. So my question is: What are the best practices for using Spring with JDBC/Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplete` used to provide the facility for translation of Hibernate 2's checked exceptions into Spring's non-checked exception hierarchy. Also, `HibernateTemplete` provided a richer API than the raw Hibernate `Session` interface.

The exception translation can now be done using the `@Repository` annotation and transparent exception translation, possible because Hibernate 3 uses runtime exceptions. Also, the `Session` interface is richer than it used to be, although it still falls short of the number of convenience methods provided by `HibernateTemplate`.

In short, these support classes aren't as useful as they used to be, and now writing Spring DAOs without reference to the Spring API is easy. However, they still provide some additional convenience, so you may choose to still use them.

There is no right or wrong approach, though.